# Update .net core nuget packages with CLI

Tags: .net-core, nuget, command-line-interface

I'm trying to write a bash script to update a nuget package for a project with the latest version from our Azure package repository.

I read somewhere that the CLI way to do this is just to add it again.

```
dotnet add myproject.csproj package X20.CQRS.Core
```

This appears to have worked once, but on subsequent runs I'm just hitting my (presumably) local cache and getting that same version, even though I can see a newer one in the repo.

```
info :   CACHE https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/4001234e-7178-480f-a784-60c97e0dcfeb/nuget/v3/flat2/aaa.cqrs.core/index.json
```

Is there a way to avoid the cache hit?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the package source using the -s option?

Comment: Sounds like you should switch to `dotnet-outdated`.

Comment: Thanks Lex, that's great. Post it as an answer and I'll give you the tick. Only issue is that there's currently no way to filter packages (but it's coming https://github.com/jerriep/dotnet-outdated/issues/55).

Answer (score 1):

A brute-force method of achieving this would be [clearing the local cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-locals) so that dotnet add package has no choice but go to your repository. Unfortunately there's no way of just removing one specific package from the cache.

Comment: There may not be any tooling support, but I wouldn't say there's no way, it's just files on the disk. You can go to `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\` on Windows, or `~/.nuget/packages` on Linux/Mac and delete a folder there to delete all versions of a single package, or delete `package id\version` to delete just the single version.

Comment: Good point. I just wasn't sure if that was all there was to it.